# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataReader'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get stock info of Pfizer (PFE)
I have tried to install Pandas and Pandas-datareader by

```
pip install pandas
pip install pandas-datareader
```

Here's my code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import datetime
start = pdr.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = pdr.datetime(2020,4,17)
pfizer = pdr.DataReader("PFE","yahoo",start,end)
pfizer.head()
```

But I got an error as followed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Vu Nguyen\Desktop\python\stock analysis.py", line 7, in <module>
pfizer = pd.DataReader("PFE", "yahoo", start, end)
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 244, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataReader'
```

Comment: How did you import pandas in your code? It looks like you are importing pandas as 'import pandas as pdr' if yes change it to pd. Also Check your working directory, you should have any .py script with the name same as import modules.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling pd.DataReader(), but the pandas module doesn't have the data reader function. pandas-datareader is the module with the DataReader() function.

If you imported pandas_datareader as pdr, call pdr.DataReader("PFE", "yahoo", start, end) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I did the change, but that seems to not solve my problem

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? How are you importing pandas_datareader?

Comment: I did "import pandas_datareader.data as pdr"

Comment: And are you getting the same error after calling pdr.DataReader("PFE", "yahoo", start, end)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import pandas as pd
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020,4,17)
pfizer = pdr.DataReader("PFE","yahoo",start,end)
pfizer.head()
```

Make sure the imports are called correctly, make sure there is no custom script in your woking dir with same name as import modules;

Comment: I reinstalled vscode and python, I only work on one file. Same error still appear in terminal.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Vu Nguyen\Desktop\python stock\pfizer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Comment: This is not the same error. It says you don't have this package in your system

Comment: I have installed the package by "pip install pandas-datareader"